# laravel how to use variable in {{trans()}}

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have a function in a controller will return `datatables` `json` which include `trans` function inside while `$type` is a variable

```
    return Datatables::of($meal)
    -> edit_column('type', '<a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/project/\' . $id ) }}}" >{{trans(\'admin/meal.$type\')}}</a>')
```

But finally `$type` is not translatable, anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Datatables::of($meal)
        -> edit_column('type', '<a href="'. URL::to('admin/project' . $id ) .'" >'.trans('admin/meal.' . $type).'</a>');
```

Comment: not worked, $type has to be defined first before passing to blade.

Comment: But this is obvious.